# Access and modify list when inheriting from list class python

Tags: python, list, oop, inheritance

I'm inheriting from the python list class but I can't seem to figure out how to modify the list itself like below:

```py
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self = [0, 0, 0, 0]

a = MyList()
print(a) # [] instead of [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Override `__str__`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM No, I would like to change the list itslef not only how it shows when you print

Comment: Subclassing `list` is a little bit tricky. Maybe you could subclass [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) instead?

Comment: `self.extend([0, 0, 0, 0])` in the init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the list in your parent's class initializer `super().__init__([0, 0, 0, 0])`. and you should notice that subclassing built-in collections may result in odd behaviors. Check [this link](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/) for more information.